# Object Oriented Programming Problem

Tags: php, oop

I'm designing a little CMS using PHP whilst putting OOP into practice. I've hit a problem though.

I have a page class, whos constructor accepts a UID and a slug. This is then used to set the properties (unless the page don't exist in which case it would fail). Anyway, I wanted to implement a function to create a page, and I thought ... what's the best way to do this without overloading the constructor. What would the correct way, or more conventional method, of doing this be?

My code is below:

```
<?php

class Page {

private $dbc;

private $title;
private $description;
private $image;
private $tags;
private $owner;
private $timestamp;
private $views;

public function __construct($uid, $slug) {

}

public function getTitle() {
    return $this->title;
}

public function getDescription() {
    if($this->description != NULL) {
        return $this->description;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function getImage() {
    if($this->image != NULL) {
        return $this->image;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function getTags() {
    if($this->tags != NULL) {
        return $this->tags;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function getOwner() {
    return $this->owner;
}

public function getTimestamp() {
    return $this->timestamp;
}

public function getViews() {
    return $this->views;
}

public function createPage() {
        // Stuck?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Doesn't support overloading. I would probably go for something like:

```
$oPage = new Page();
$oPage->setTitle($sSomeTitle);
$oPage->setcontent($sSomeContent);
$oPage->save();
```

Or you could create an extra object - that is responsible for handling this.

```
$oPage = new Page();
$oPage->setTitle($sSomeTitle);
$oPage->setcontent($sSomeContent);
PageManager::create($oPage);
```

The advantage of this - is that your page class remains a pure data container, where all logic for loading/saving is done within an separate class.

Comment: Fortunatly this site isn't about enforcing GuidoH's personal preferences and coding standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can make **static** method, that returns Page object

```
public static function CreatePageWithExtraAttribute($uid, $slug, $extra) {
    $page = new Page($uid,$slug);
    //your code here
    return $page;
}
```

Or make a static method that querys database for example

```
public static function CreatePage($extra) {
    list($uid,$slug) = SomeDatabaseManager::GetUidSlug();
    $page = new Page($uid,$slug);
    //your code here
    return $page;
}
```

Then use it

```
$page=Page::CreatePageWithExtraAttribute($title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I put those arguments in a constructor without which an object cannot exist. Other (optional) attributes of an object can be set by calling its setters.

For example, in your case a page seems to always have a UID, without which your system cannot recognize it, so it should be an argument to the constructor and I would build it such that the callee of the constructor shall not be able to call an empty constructor, because it won't mean anything for the page class.

A page can have no content and not even any title, but it has no meaning for the system without a UID or for example a URI. So my callee's code would look as follows:

```
$page = new Page($uid);
$page->setTitle($sSomeTitle);
$page->setcontent($sSomeContent);
$page->render();
```

However, my discussion mainly pertains to modelling your class. I personally think that the second solution in [Wesley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464747/object-oriented-programming-problem/6464775#6464775) is better.

Comment: The UID is the database UID when the page is created. It would not be possible to define a UID without querying the database which would create overheads.

Comment: Then, you have answered your own question. A `Page` means to your system even without the UID. But I have mentioned a very generalized design argument.